# For loop only running for last case

Tags: python

The main aim of the code is to take n lines of input and add this data to dictionary and then perform n queries on dictionary. however only the last query is working correctly.

```
   from sys import stdin
n = int(input())
mydict={}
for i in range(0,n):
    pairs=input().split(' ')
    key=pairs[0]
    value=pairs[1]
    mydict[key]=value
    print (mydict)


for a in stdin:
    print(a)
    if(a in mydict):
        print(a+'='+mydict[a])
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

Comment: Do you input the correct data? You should fix the indentation.

Comment: Yes i verified it by printing the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The input obtained from `stdin` includes the new line character(s), however, due to the use of `input()` the keys in the dictionary do not, hence the lookup fails. It works on the final iteration because the line is terminated by end of file rather than new line.

You could fix it by stripping whitespace at the end of the line in the second loop:

```
for a in stdin:
    a = a.rstrip()
    print(a)
    if a in mydict:
        print(a+'='+mydict[a])
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

**The content read from stdin is original stream.**

So when you hit the enter key, the `'\n'` is add to the stream.

**Solution 1: use input method.**

**Solution 2: read from stdin, and use `rstrip()` method before query from the dict.**